# Ftp клиент на сайт для посетителей. PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите как организовать FTP клиент на сайте для не зарегистрированных пользователей, без авторизации на ftp сервере. Как сохранить соединение с ftp сервером, если это вообще нужно? Интересует как подойти к этому архитектурно. Были мысли создать демона, чтобы он отвечал за выдачу нужных директорий пользователям. Еще была мысль синхронизироваться с ftp сервером и хранить ссылки на файлы и директории в базе... Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/21461/

Comment: Как это может помочь?

Comment: @ГригорийСветланин один вопрос - зачем это делать через FTP?

Comment: Заказчику необходимо показывать файлы на сайте для скачивания. На нем лежат свои разработки, документы, маркетинговые материалы и они хотят именно фтп. Т.е получается должен результат быть таким - сайт выступает в роли посредника между пользователями и FTP сервером.

Comment: Я так и не понял, чем вам не подходит net2ftp или его аналоги (коих много)?

Comment: Я ж не сказал, что не подходит, я не понимаю, что он делает. сейчас изучаю, что это. Оказывается, что это не только онлайн сервис, еще его можно развернуть у себя на сервере Development version

Comment: По net2ftp  Я не понимаю немного, допустим зашло 100 пользователей на сайт сколько коннектов будет создано к фтп серверу?